# my computer does't want to start after I changed the boot order in the bios

Tags: windows, boot, bios

I am having some issues with my pc.
I was re installing windows, so I changed the boot order on my asus p8h61/usb3. after the computer restarted itself I didn't get response. my usb devices get no power like the computer is powered down and I am not getting a video signal. but the hardware is all running and all 
components get power.

can somebody please help me.

thanks in advance,
Dylan reimerink

Comment: What USB configuration BIOS settings does your system have?

Answer (score 2):

If you altered BIOS configuration and now can't even boot, then you need to reset CMOS. Unplug your computer from power, remove battery from your motherboard and leave it like that for 5minutes. The BIOS should reset to defaults and you should boot again.

Also if you have installed any new hardware before this started happening (internal hardware or USB), unplug it before starting your computer again.

Comment: I have tried to clear the cmos but the situation didn't change

Comment: Also did you add add any new hardware to you computer before this problem started? If so, remove it. Maybe there is some USB plugged in in some USB port? Unplug it.

Comment: I replace the harddrive but I think that can't course the problem of being unable to access even the bios

Comment: Unplug it and check it, it is likely the cause.